# PHP Run query on SHOW TABLES results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I go about running a query on tables from a previous SHOW TABLES query? What I'm trying to do is create a PHP script that runs every 24 hours that sorts a table by "verified" descending and "votes" descending and update "nomnom" on the top result, for every table in the database.

```
$result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES");

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $sql = "SET @clan = (SELECT clan FROM " . $row[0] . " ORDER BY verified DESC, votes DESC LIMIT 1); UPDATE " . $row[0] . " SET nomnom=0 verified=0; UPDATE " . $row[0] . " SET nomnom=1 WHERE clan=@clan";
        $conn->query($sql);
        echo $row[0] . ' done<br>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'query 0';
}
```

This correctly echos every table name followed by done, but isn't actually updating the tables. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

So I've determined that the following should work:

```
$sql = "SET @clan := (SELECT `clan` FROM " . $row[0] . " ORDER BY `verified` DESC, `votes` DESC LIMIT 1); UPDATE " . $row[0] . " SET `nomnom`=0, `verified`=0; UPDATE " . $row[0] . " SET `nomnom`=1 WHERE `clan`=@clan";
```

by echoing $sql and running the queries returned through phpmyadmin without changing anything. 
Here's a line that is echoed.

> SET @clan := (SELECT `clan` FROM aerngardh ORDER BY `verified` DESC, `votes` DESC LIMIT 1); UPDATE aerngardh SET `nomnom`=0, `verified`=0; UPDATE aerngardh SET `nomnom`=1 WHERE `clan`=@clan

It just for some reason isn't actually doing it when using

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Figured out a way to make it work. Would mark my answer but I can't for 2 days...

Comment: try to explain more .Please

Comment: Looks like you are missing an update before the first set statement, I am betting if you tried to run your statements in phpmysql they would fail.

Comment: Have you tried echoing your query and running it in db

Comment: @HassanALi the second query, set by $sql, is for setting @clan to order each table (results from the first query) correctly then limit to the first row so that `@clan` is only returning the top row. 
After that it sets verified to 0 and resets nomnom for every row in the table and then finally sets `@clan`'s nomnom to 1.

But the code is completely ignoring the second query yet echoing correctly.

Comment: @coder Good idea. It's actually not setting the `@clan` variable to be used... Echo result is this `SET @clan = (SELECT clan FROM aerngardh ORDER BY verified DESC, votes DESC LIMIT 1); UPDATE aerngardh SET nomnom=0 verified=0; UPDATE aerngardh SET nomnom=1 WHERE clan=@clan`

Comment: what  is  clan in your db?

Comment: @JoshQuake, Plz check my ans

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$sql = SET @clan := (SELECT clan FROM aerngardh ORDER BY verified DESC, votes DESC LIMIT 1); UPDATE aerngardh SET nomnom=0, verified=0; UPDATE aerngardh SET nomnom=1 WHERE clan=@clan
```

This should work

Comment: That didn't work either. I have tested the query on a single table in phpmyadmin to make sure that the query actually does what I want and it does update the table correctly, but it seems to not be setting the `@clan` variable nor trying to use that variable when done through PHP.

Comment: no dont try it in db.try it in the browser as the values are being added later

Comment: Right, that's what I mean. I just changed the PHP file and ran it but it didn't work. I ALSO tried this query to make sure that it does work. `SET @clan = (SELECT clan FROM aerngardh ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 1);
UPDATE aerngardh SET nomnom=0 verified=0;
UPDATE aerngardh SET nomnom=1 WHERE clan=@clan` and it correctly uses the `@clan` variable to update.

Comment: so @clan value is set?

Comment: Yeah. I actually just noticed that I missed SELECT before `clan` when setting the variable. And then I had it run and echo the query. It still didn't update, but if I take the echo and run it in phpmyadmin it works without changing anything...

Comment: this is the first echo that I copied and pasted into phpmyadmin: ``SET @clan := (SELECT `clan` FROM aerngardh ORDER BY verified DESC, votes DESC LIMIT 1); UPDATE aerngardh SET nomnom=0, verified=0; UPDATE aerngardh SET nomnom=1 WHERE clan=@clan`` and it works. so now just need to figure out why the query seems to not actually run from the PHP file.

Comment: change `clan` in select clause in the above mentioned query(by you) to clan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120450/discussion-between-joshquake-and-coder).

Answer (score 0):

Had to split the query into 3 separate queries. Full working code:

```
$conn = new MySQLi($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES");

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $sql = "SET @clan := (SELECT clan FROM " . $row[0] . " ORDER BY verified DESC, votes DESC LIMIT 1);";
        $sql2 = "UPDATE " . $row[0] . " SET nomnom=0, verified=0;";
        $sql3 = "UPDATE " . $row[0] . " SET nomnom=1 WHERE clan=@clan";
        $conn->query($sql);
        echo $conn->error . '<br>';
        $conn->query($sql2);
        echo $conn->error . '<br>';
        $conn->query($sql3);
        echo $conn->error . '<br>';

    }
} else {
    echo 'query 0';
}
```

If anyone would like to post how to make this a proper multi_query without getting queries out of sync errors, be my guest. I cba doing that lol.